# cannot build pull requests with teamcity

Tags: git, teamcity

I am using teamcity 9 and trying to integrate with github. I have followed the arcticle

https://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2013/02/automatically-building-pull-requests-from-github-with-teamcity/

http://michaelsync.net/2014/04/05/teamcity-tip-building-all-pull-requests-and-updating-the-status-to-github

i have tried the various combinations

```
+:refs/pull/*/merge
+:refs/pull/(*/merge)
```

the default branch in master only

but whenever i click the 'run' button it always triggers the master build only. Can anyone please help on where am i going wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click run in TeamCity, it will always build from the default branch.

The articles make no mention about Triggers. Provided you've got a trigger that is of the type VCS Trigger, then this should automatically build your pull requests.

Alternatively, you can manually trigger a build of the Pull Request using a custom run and choosing the build branch to be the PR required

[image]

Hope this helps